# What are the most common non-universal rules across all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

I often find myself not using some of the trickier parts of Stack Exchange, like recommending edits to people's answers, because I participate in a lot of Stack Exchange sites, and they all have different guidelines and rules. Sometimes I get something wrong anyway, but I try to stick to the most commonly acceptable behaviors.

Is that information aggregated anywhere? Has anyone gone through all the Stack Exchange sites and figured out which rule or behavior or expectation quirks are rare or common?

This question is not a duplicate of the main FAQ. The main FAQ covers SE-wide rules. I am looking for the most common non-universal rules across all the separate site FAQs.

Comment: [FAQ for Stack Exchange Sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: I'm not exactly looking for the FAQ. Most of the things in the FAQ are the same across all SE sites. I'm looking for just the stuff that's notably different on many SE sites, with documentation of the "lowest common denominator" or at least the most common solution for a given concern.

Comment: @Sparr Most sites have their own site-specific FAQ posts on their metas.  See for example on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) and [Meta Gaming Stack Exchange](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Comment: @JAL I know. What I'm looking for is a distillation of all the site FAQs into the things that are most common across all sites but not universal (the universal things are in the main SE FAQ this is marked as a duplicate of)

Comment: @Sparr- This is indeed a duplicate.  The information your looking for is in the help center for each website.

Comment: @Ramhound I think one of us might be confused about what "a duplicate" is here. If the information I'm looking for is spread out among 50 other Questions, then this isn't a duplicate of any one or all of those questions.

Comment: I am not the one that is confused.  Your original question wanted the common rules across all SE sites.  The duplicate covers that.  You changing the title of the question, 2 months later, was ill-advised.  *You went wanting the common rules to the site specific rules.*

Comment: No, the duplicate is the rules/guidelines for the SE network. I wouldn't call those rules of individual sites at all. I've changed the title to make it more obvious what I'm looking for, but that doesn't change that what I asked originally was still what I meant.